# Extension of valuation ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

> Let $K$ be a field, and $R$ an integrally closed subdomain of $K$ with $K$ as it's quotient field. Let $(R_{\alpha})$ be a family of valuation rings of $K$ with $\cap_{\alpha}R_{\alpha}=R$. Show that the integral closure of $R$ in $L$, an extension field of $K$, is the intersection of all valuation rings of $L$ which dominate one of the $R_{\alpha}$.

I have been trying it for so long now but unable to solve the problem. So any help will be appreciated about this problem. Thanks

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: Well I was able to solve it If we consider the family of $R_{\alpha}$ to be the complete set of valuation ring containing R. Then we can show that for each valuation ring in $L$, containing R dominates at least one of the $R_{\alpha}$ and hence we can show it easily. But over here, they have given that $R_{\alpha}$ is a family of valuation ring,rather than the complete set of valuation ring containing $R$, because of which I am unable to solve.